# How to read, write, and set block value and direction/rotation - Spigot 1.16.3+

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

i want to get block material and direction/rotation, then save it to .txt file and in future reading this data and set material and direction/rotation for another block

I try to get material something like this:

```
tempLocation.getBlock().getType().toString()
```

for example when block is LOG, it does not distinguish the type and returns just "LOG", thus it does not recognize the type of LOG, For example i would like to write information about this is a jungle log.

Another case when I want to save the direction/rotation of a block and set it for another block in the future, i try used:

```
tempLocation.getBlock().getState().getData().toString()
```

but it returns the material information to me as is:

```
LEGACY_DIRT(0)
```

but I don't know how to use this information to set the direction of the block

I am using spigot version 1.16.3
I saw that a lot has changed since version 1.13+. How can I now correctly retrieve material type and block direction/rotation, and how to set this information without using outdated interfaces?

Comment: tomorrow I'll try using `getBlockData().getAsString()` and `setBlockData(Bukkit.getServer().createBlockData(takenAsString))`

Answer (score 0):

For people with a similar problem

I solved my problem by using:

```
getBlockData().getAsString()
```

and

```
setBlockData(Bukkit.getServer().createBlockData(takenAsString))
```